# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Is it possible to replace a file in an existing Docker Container stored an Azure Container Registry?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, docker, azure-devops, yaml

Is it possible to make changes, in my case replacing a file, to a container stored in an Azure Container Registry from an Azure deployment pipeline (i.e. yaml)?

I currently have a pipeline set up that packages and deploys a Spring Boot application as a Docker container using a Web App that pulls the latest image from a Container Registry. In our current setup, we have a `application.properties` file full with tokens that are filled in during this deployment process using variables. It happens that we want to update a property (variable) in this file without any other code changes. In such case, we would like to simply be able to replace the file and restart the Web App instead of having to go through the full pipeline again (including building, packaging, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make changes, in my case replacing a file, to a container stored in an Azure Container Registry from an Azure deployment pipeline (i.e. yaml)?

Yes, we can use the docker command to pull the docker image and replace the file in the image. Finally, we can push the docker image(same tag) back to the ACR.

In this case, the new version of the docker version will override the existing docker image with the same tag.

Here is the example:

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: AzureSub
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     az acr login --name containerregistryname
     docker pull containerregistryname.azurecr.io/reponame:sametag
     docker run --name foo  -d containerregistryname.azurecr.io/reponame:sametag
     docker ps -a
     docker cp filepath  foo:/pathinthecontainer
     docker exec foo ls  /pathinthecontainer
     docker commit foo containerregistryname.azurecr.io/reponame:sametag
     docker image ls
     docker push containerregistryname.azurecr.io/reponame:sametag
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to the doc: [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)